# Paginate Link generate additional #038; whenever my Url have multiple Query String

Tags: paginate-links, query-string

My generated paginate link results will have additional `#038;` in the url, may I know how to get rid of it?

---

**Blog page url :**
`http://localhost/wordpress/blog/`

I had already setup pagination with function [paginate_links](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/), when I press page [2] :

**Blog page Page 2 url :**
`http://localhost/wordpress/blog/page/2/`

( everything is fine above )

---

However, whenever my Blog page URL have certain parameters which is for my filter/sorting purposes for WP_Query, the paginate_link result will have additional *#038* params , please refer below for the URL

**Blog page with Params Url :**
`http://localhost/wordpress/blog/?filter=23&orderby=oldest`

**Blog page with Params Page 2 Url :** 
`http://localhost/wordpress/blog/page/2/?filter=23&orderby=oldest#038;orderby=oldest`

---

The URL I need to achieve is
`http://localhost/wordpress/blog/page/2/?filter=23&orderby=oldest`

below are my paginate_links functions:

```
global $wp_query;
$big = 99999999999;    

paginate_links([
    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_text' => __('&lt;'),
    'next_text' => __('&gt;'),
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'type'      => 'list',
    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    ]);
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619226/page-navigation-stopped-working-after-updating-wordpress ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to escape the URL twice - [`get_pagenum_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pagenum_link/) by default returns an escaped URL — when the second parameter is `true`, [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) is used; else, [`esc_url_raw()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url_raw/) is used:

- With `esc_url()`: `http://localhost/wordpress/blog/?filter=23&#038;orderby=oldest`
- With `esc_url_raw()`: `http://localhost/wordpress/blog/?filter=23&orderby=oldest`

**And the problem occurs when the `base` contains `?`, or a query string, and that the URL is escaped (e.g. using `esc_url()`).**

Because `esc_url()` converts `&` (ampersand) to its HTML entity, which is `&#038;`, and when the `base` contains a query string, `paginate_links()` will parse the `base` value/URL, and when the `&` is escaped, anything after each `&` and the nearest `=` is treated as a query string *name*/key, and added to the `base`'s query string:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/blog/?filter=23&orderby=oldest#038;orderby=oldest
```

In the above example, the URL is like that because `paginate_links()` (or more precisely, `wp_parse_str()` [used](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L3738) in [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/)) interpreted `#038;orderby` as the key of `oldest`; i.e. `#038;orderby=oldest` — it should be `&orderby=oldest` where the key is `orderby`.

(But of course, the browser sees anything after the `#` as a URL fragment. And if you follow the link, on the next page, `$_GET` will not have an entry for `#038;orderby`; i.e. `$_GET['#038;orderby']` doesn't exist.)

***So here are several ways to fix/avoid the problem:***

1. Use `html_entity_decode()` just as WordPress [does](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L3694) via `paginate_links()`:

   ```
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) )
   ```
2. When you call `get_pagenum_link()`, set the second parameter set to `false`:

   ```
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big, false ) )
   ```
3. Use `str_replace()` to replace the `&#038;` with `&`:

   ```
   'base' => str_replace( [ $big, '&#038;' ], [ '%#%', '&' ], get_pagenum_link( $big ) )
   ```

Don't worry about not escaping the `base` because `paginate_links()` actually escapes all the links/URLs in the returned result.

*Friendly Warning: Some of the links in this answer point you to a huge HTML file / web page..*

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31060) with `paginate_links` function.

Here's a quick workaround, which will work well, if only there are no ampersands in your query params values:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 99999999999;

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base'      => str_replace( array($big, '#038;'), array('%#%', ''), esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
        'prev_text' => __('&lt;'),
        'next_text' => __('&gt;'),
        'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'type'      => 'list',
        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    ));
?>
```